# How to split my String into 3 delimited Strings (regardless of SubString Length)?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ibm-midrange

I'm storing strings in an array. An example would be:

```
ssnDateTime = "123456789|20140225|114528"
```

I was attempting to store each substring into it's own variable for use, like the below:

```
string SSN  = ssnDateTime.Substring(0, 9);
string Date = ssnDateTime.Substring(ssnDateTime.Length - 15, 8);
string Time = ssnDateTime.Substring(19);
```

This worked fine for 5 of my 10 test records, but the 6th has a time value of `91514`, leading to my 3 strings being:

```
SSN = 123456789
Date = |2014022
Time = 91514
```

When my application attempts to run `INSERT INTO Library.TrackingTable (SSN, DATE, TIME) VALUES ("123456789", "|2014021", "91514")`, The AS400 naturally complains about the `|` in the Date value.

What is a way I can get each of the SSN, Date, and Time values out of my main string with the delimiters, regardless of the substring length (to prevent the mentioned issue when time is a shorter value than 6 characters)?

SSN will naturally be consistently 9 characters, and Date will be in the 8 character format of `20140225`, but Time can be either the 5 or 6 characters depending on value.

Comment: Did you ever used string.Split(char)?

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about those SSN's being plain text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a perfect fit for [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 ssnDateTime = "123456789|20140225|114528"
 string[] subs = ssnDateTime.Split('|');
 string SSN  = subs[0];
 string Date = subs[1];
 string Time = subs[2];
```

string.Split returns an array of strings splitting the orginal string at the separator passed as argument.

Of course this code doesn't check if the resulting string array contains really three elements, in a production environment a check like

```
 if(subs.Length > 0
     date = subs[1];
 if(subs.Length > 1)
    Time = subs[2];
```

should be mandatory....

Comment: thanks so much! I knew there was a way I had done this before, but could not for the life of me recall how. This is the solution I was trying to think of :)

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] parts = "123456789|20140225|114528".Split('|');
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: I also noticed the downvotes and was curious as to why they were occuring?